# Javascript Intellisense not working on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense, visual-studio-2010

I've just got the new Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Javascript Intellisense is not working on .aspx/.ascx files inside  blocks. It does work on external .js files.

After VS2010 setup, it asked me if I wanted to import the settings from previous VS version (I have VS2008 SP1 installed), I say yes.
I've tried resetting the settings like explained [here](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/50857.aspx). Didn't work.

I've also installed Resharper 5. I thought it might be conflicting, so I tried suspending it like it says [here](http://mshelp.be/disabling-resharper-5-0-275.htm). Didn't work.

Anyone experiencing the same issue? I really want javascript/jQuery intellisense =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed.

I reset the settings again and restarted Visual Studio and now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let you know that those guy's who use master pages can use the following on the master page to enable jquery intellisense:

```
<% if (false)
   { %>
   <script src='/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<% } %>
```